# How to make a macro that replace string in Excel

Tags: excel, regex, vba, notepad++

Does anyone know how to make a macro in Excel that convert strings ?
I want to convert all strings existing in one column respecting this transformation :

| initial | result of macro |
| --- | --- |
| first_name | $firstName |
| last_name | $lastName |
| email | $email |
| email2 | $email2 |

I would like to transform in Uppercase after the underscore if it's a caracter.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your question is unclear, please add sample text and expected result.

Comment: I don't understand, you have only one word per line or are these words inside multiline text? What to do when underscore is at the beginning or at the end of a word? Why are you talking about macro, isn't a find and replace sufficient?

Comment: You're no more interested by a Notepad++ solution?

Comment: @Toto Actually, I just need to convert values, the software doesn't matter for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Notepad++ solution:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^([^\W_]+)|\G(?!^))(?:_([^\W_]*))?`
- Replace with: `(?1\$$1)\u$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    ^               # beginning of line
    (               # group 1
        [^\W_]+         # 1 or more non non-word character or underscore
    )               # end group 1
  |               # OR
    \G(?!^)         # restart from last match position, not at the beginning of lie
)               # end grroup
(?:             # non capture group
    _               # underscore
    (               # group 2
        [^\W_]*         # 0 or more non non-word character or underscore
    )               # end group 1
)               # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1             # if group 1 exists
    \$$1            # add a dollar before the group 1
)               # endif
\u$1            # uppercase the first letter of group 2
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]